# Cannot break long string of words in html email in Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm working on an html email and sometimes the content has a long string of characters like so:

`"[Line:3, Email: The field Email must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '1000'.] "A","32651","0","Missouri River Marine","","","4250 Lower River Rd.","","Great Falls","MT","59405","US","406761-1851","","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@JRwZSi.irZambVkQmQN"`

For the life of me I cannot get Outlook on Android to break the characters. word-break: break-all does not work;

Answer (score 0):

Use the `style="word-break:break-all;"` code.

It worked for me in all Outlook versions. Please see the screenshot[image]

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" />
  <title>*|MC:SUBJECT|*</title>
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <style>
    table {
    border-collapse:collapse !important;
    }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
 </head>
 <body style="Margin:0;padding-top:50px;padding-bottom:50px;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;min-width:100%;background-color:#ffffff;">
  <center class="wrapper" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
   <div class="webkit" style="max-width:627px;">
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <table width="627" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;">
      <tr>
     <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
       <![endif]-->
    <table class="outer" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#4A4A4A;margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:627px;">
     <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" style="border:1px solid #E5E5E5;">
       <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="height:100%;">
        <tr>
         <td align="center" valign="top">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
           <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top" width="100%" style="word-break:break-all;">
11111111111122222222222222222222222233333333333333333333444444444444444444445555555555555555555566666666666666667777777777777777777788888888888888888888888889999999999999999999999999999999990000000000000000000000000000000
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```